# How to run ffmpeg command in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I need to run the ffmpeg command in the PHP.

But php-ffmpeg is no more supports the latest version and out of date.

May i know alternate way to run the ffmpeg command in the webfile (PHP,Javascript,jQuery).

I try the `exec()` and `shell_exec()` in the PHP file but gets the blank output.

```
echo shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  -i test.mp3  -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k out.mp3");
```

and

```
 echo shell_exec("ffmpeg  -i test.mp3  -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k  out.mp3");
```

Comment: at server side you can try `exec('ffmpeg .....');`

Comment: @Santa'shelper i try exec() and shell_exec() but blank output is there. will you plz let me know syntax for change mp3 bitrate. so i clear i did'nt go wrong.

Comment: i am not very good at ffmpeg but it should be look like 
`exec('ffmpeg -i /path/to/my.mp3 -r 44100 /path/to/target.mp3', $output);
var_dump($output);`
Warning: i am not pretty sure about the -ar 44100

Answer (score 18):

ffmpeg outputs on stderr, so you need to redirect the output. Add `2>&1` to your command line:

```
echo shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k out.mp3 2>&1");
```

Then you will see the output.

Comment: 2 points to note here: 1) there must be a space prior to the 2 and 2) you must use double quotes not single

Comment: i do not understand one thing when i run the file in the browser is ge no such file or directory but when i run in terminal thing are okay  Please help

Comment: @mwangaben What do you mean by "file" – do you mean you want to run `ffmpeg`? Make sure that you either call the full path to ffmpeg (e.g., `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`) or that your `$PATH` in PHP contains the folder where `ffmpeg` is.

Answer (score 3):

use **FFMpeg\FFMpeg**, you can install with composer: **"php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg"**: "0.5.*@dev" ([FFMpeg\FFMpeg Git Repository](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg))

**Or**

use **Symfony Process**, you can install with composer: **"symfony/process"     : "~2.0"** ([Symfony Process Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html))

**Or**

use **proc_open()** function.

**FFMpeg\FFMpeg** used **Symfony Process** and **Symfony Process** used **proc_open()** function :)

I prefer to use Symfony Process:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->run();
```

Comment: This is all overkill and not related to the OP's problem, which is a simple shell redirection issue.

Comment: this should not be downvoted. The OP did ask for alternative ways to run ffmpeg from a PHP script, which is what this answers to.

Comment: Was deciphering how proc_open works, turns out I had Symfony available and this was much cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

first you have to install ffmpeg library in your server. with out install ffmpeg in your server command will not run.

the following link will help you

https://ffmpeg.org/

https://www.resellerspanel.com/articles/dedicated-servers-articles/dedicated-servers-howtos/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-a-dedicated-server/

then after run this command

```
 exec("ffmpeg  -i test.mp3  -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k  out.mp3");
```