# Insert text on top of video canvas, and export as MP4

Tags: html, video, browser, renderer

Let's say you have a HTML5 `<video>` element with an MP4 video source:

```css
#video { width: 400px; }
#text { font-size: 30px; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<video controls id="video"><source src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4">
<span id="text">Hello world</span>
</video><br>
<button>Export</button>
```

The `<span>` here is invisible, is there a way to make it visible on top of the video canvas, such that **we can export the video + text as a new MP4 (rendered) video?**

I can imagine this is nowadays included in some browser API, without the need of an external library, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

short answer ... not easily.

You can push the video to a canvas, overlay the text, and then use something like https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy to save the canvas as a video but there will be a corresponding loss of fidelity along the way.

Far better would be to use something like ffmpeg server side as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/1569675) and trigger it from your web page (eg [using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913178/1569675)) and then present the output once completed to the user